# Modal not displayed

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I have placed a sample modal in the front end of my application.

The modal is the following:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
             <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
 </div>
```

I got the code for the modal from here:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

The modal is nested like this:

```
<div className="col-md-4 no-padding max-height-col">
    <div className="panel panel-default no-padding max-height">
      <div className="panel-heading" >
        <h2 className="panel-title headingText">
            Attributes   <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>

            <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, when I deploy the code to the server, the modal's code does not appear in the page.
I am certain that I am building and deploying correctly.
Any ideas about why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure your scripts are all import correctly ?

Comment: Pleasse post a jsfiddle example or similar. The example code here http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h works fine. It is important to include bootstrap.css, jquery.js and bootstrap.js correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that you haven't imported all the required libs. You have to know that bootstrap require JQuery and if you don't include it your modal won't be displayed. This example work (I put also the include of JQuery)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello</title>
      <link href='bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src='bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

         <!-- Modal content-->
         <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
             <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
             <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```